# why i am getting 0 at first, while parsing JSON data?

Tags: php, json

I am new to json, my aim is to maintain the history of specific columns(which are posted through $_POST in php) on every update in mysql using php. I took one json array for the history column and placed it in a while loop, after that I appended the variable which i want to merge with the previous one with `array_merge()` function. I am getting the output but starting with 0. Let me know how to append the required fields in a proper json format and also how to retrieve the json data in a div tag. Thanks in advance.

PHP Code:

```
<?php
$query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT `history` FROM projects WHERE `no` = '$id'");
  $json_data = array();
     while ($js = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) 
     {
       $json_data[] = $js['history'];
       $j = $json_data;
     }
?>  

 <?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  if(isset($_GET['id'])){
  $id = $_GET['id'];
  $assign = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['assign']);
  $end_date = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['end_date']);
  $comments = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['comments']);

  $end_date = [
      'assigned_to' => $assign,
      'end_date' => $end_date,
      'comments' => $comments
     ];
 $json = array_merge($j,$end_date);
 $js = json_encode($json);
$ins = mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE `projects` SET `assigned_to`='$assign',`end_date`='$end_date',
 `status`='$status',`comments`='$comments'`history`= '$js'  WHERE 
`episode_no` = '$id'");
}
}
?>
```

JSON data in MYSQL :

```
{"0":"{"0":"{"0":"","assigned_to":"AAA","end_date":"2018-09-12","comments":"happy"}",
        "assigned_to":"AAA","end_date":"2018-09-12","comments":"jolly"}",
        "assigned_to":"AAA","end_date":"2018-09-12","comments":"xvbcvbdfghdfg"}
```

Comment: My guess is you need `$json_data[] = json_decode($js['history']);` instead.

Comment: Just append `$end_data` exactly like the DB rows: https://ideone.com/Ab6ttv

Comment: I just saw that you want it to accumulate, yes? In that case, shouldn't you just read a single `history` entry, namely the immediately preceding one?

Comment: I tried it the json data is coming like this now,    [[[null,{"assigned_to":"Jyothi","end_date":"2018-09-04","comments":"now"}],
{"assigned_to":"Jyothi","end_date":"2018-09-17","comments":"hgfghfghfgh"}],
{"assigned_to":"Jyothi","end_date":"2018-09-05","comments":"BBBBB"}]

Comment: Yes, how can i display the above json in a html div tag in a proper way?

Comment: My point about the accumulation was that it seems like instead of a -> a,b -> a,b,c -> a,b,c,d your current code seems to produce a -> [a],b -> [[a],[a],b],c etc. Is this what you want?

Comment: No, I need it like "history[ {a->a,b->b,c->c},{a->a1,b->b1,c->c1},......]" . This format have to store in DB as well as by using this only want to retrieve in html format.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. At the start of your code, you are reading *multiple* rows, building an array. Then you append new data and write that to a single row. How many rows `WHERE \`no\` = '$id'` are there? And is your UPDATE command updating multiple rows? because it says `\`episode_no\` = '$id'`

Comment: There are upto 10 rows but I am updating only three which i want to get them in one column and display like history in html page.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the answer to your question: you are loading an array of strings in `$j`, so the `array_merge` function won't work as expected:

```
$j[0] = 'some JSON string from DB';

$json = array_merge($j, $end_date);
```

the `array_merge` finds that the second argument is a sparse array, so it merges the keys as strings:

```
$json = [
  '0' => 'the previous string',
  'assigned_to' => ...
]
```

For your idea to work you probably need to store the new history item by *appending* to the array:

```
$j[] = $end_date;
$js = json_encode($j);
...
```

This would solve your issue.

But there is a very major issue here that you need to solve first. It's a OMG-like WTF-like issue. You are getting `$id` from user input (query parameters) and sending it to the DB without any fear. Suppose that the user sends

```
https://your.server/some/path?id=';TRUNCATE TABLE projects --'
```

(propery url-encoded of course). Now you are sending this to the database:

```
SELECT `history` FROM projects WHERE `no` = '';TRUNCATE TABLE projects --''
```

Bye bye projects. A user can do whatever to your database, change passwords, reassign foreign keys, set himself as administrator.

Please for the sake of whatever you believe in, use a proper ORM and *never* pass user input to the DB!!!

Comment: Thanks for the wake up call @rewritten can you suggest, how to achieve the thing without passing the id to DB or else how to hide the unnecessary data from the url ?

Comment: By using the array_merge I am getting like this ,  
{"0":["{"0":[""],"assigned_to":"Jyothi","end_date":"2018-09-12","comments":"happy happy"}"],
                 "assigned_to":"Jyothi","end_date":"2018-09-11","comments":"BBBBB"}.    Another method is like this  [["[[""],{"assigned_to":"Jyothi","end_date":"2018-09-05","comments":"happy happy"}]"],
         {"assigned_to":"Jyothi","end_date":"2018-09-12","comments":"BBBBB"}].

Comment: About the SQL injection, I suppose you can use `mysqli_real_escape_string($id)` instead. A test should show the result. About merging, I am actually saying you shouldn't use array_merge for the reasons given above. Just json-decode, and append to the decoded array using `$j[] = $end_date;`.